# Regex to match GSM character set

Tags: python, regex

This is a GSM character set (below). I need to make sure only text containing these
characters will match. If the text contains anything outside this scope if will not match...

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567889@?£_!1$"¥#è
?¤é%ù&ì\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿'
```

This is what I have tried...

```
@£$¥èéùìòÇ\fØø\nÅåΔ_ΦΓΛΩΠΨΣΘΞÆæßÉ !\"#¤%&'()*+,-./[0-9]:;<=>\?¡[A-Z]ÄÖÑÜ§¿[a-z]äöñüà\^\{\}\[~\]\|€
```

I need a regex that only matches the following

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567889@?£_!1$"¥#è
?¤é%ù&ì\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿'
```

how? Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

```
 rule = re.compile(r'^[\w@?£!1$"¥#è?¤é%ù&ì\\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ\-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿\']+$')

    if not rule.search(value):
        msg = u"Invalid characters."
        raise ValidationError(msg)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
r'^[\w@?£!1$"¥#è?¤é%ù&ì\\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ\-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿\']+$'
```

If you want to match the above characters within a string which also contains other characters then remove the leading `^` and trailing `$`.

Note that the above will not allow space characters. If you want to include them just add a space (or add `\s` if you want to include newlines also) to the set.

Comment: I get an error Non-ASCII character '\xc2' with that re.compile(r'^[\w@?£!1$"¥#è?¤é%ù&ì\\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ\-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿\']+$')

Comment: @MarkO. Strange, I don't. Try removing characters until it works, and check the encoding of your editor.

Comment: @ MikeM I have updated the question so you can see the code giving the error.

Comment: Try adding `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach without using regular expressions:

```
>>> valid_chars = set(u'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567889@?£_!1$"¥#è?¤é%ù&ì\ò(Ç)*:Ø+;ÄäøÆ,<LÖlöæ-=ÑñÅß.>ÜüåÉ/§à¡¿\'')
>>> tests = ['hello', u'£_!', u'Ϡ']
>>> [len(set(t).difference(valid_chars)) == 0 for t in tests]
[True, True, False]
```